# Pig: Output 1 column

Tags: java, apache-pig

Say I have a data file:

```
abc,def,ghi
jkl,mno,pqr
stu,vwx,yz
```

How can I output only 1 column, so that I get to following?

```
abc
jkl
stu
```

This was my idea:

```
A = load 'data'  AS (c1,c2,c3);
dump A.c1
```

I get this error:

```
2014-12-06 17:14:19,424 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered " <PATH> "data.c1 "" at line 2, column 6.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "cat" ...
    "clear" ...
    "fs" ...
    "sh" ...
    "cd" ...
    "cp" ...
    "copyFromLocal" ...
```

Comment: Generally, be more specific than "it doesn't work".  Show what the output really was or what error you were getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like this?

```
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(',') AS (c1,c2,c3);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE c1;
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(abc)
(jkl)
(stu)
```

Comment: I forgot `USING PigStorage(',')`. Thank you!